# To get the hosted web sites names from IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, com, .net-assembly

I have created a method to get hosted web sites from IIS server as following code snippet.

```
       ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager();

        try
        {
            foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(site);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

When i run it in my local machine it's working perfectly`(Windows 7 /IIS 7 with 32bits)`.but when i run it in server machine`(Windows server 2003 R2 with IIS 6)` it's not working.It gives following Error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B> 
>   52-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154> 
>   d (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Any help will be great full ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `System.DirectoryServices` instead of using `Microsoft.Web.Administration` and it solved my problem.It will work with the IIS6 and IIS7 as well.

```
    public class IisManager
    {
        public static int IisVersion
        {
            get
            {
                int iisVersion;

                using (RegistryKey iisKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\InetStp"))
                {
                    if (iisKey == null)
                        throw new Exception("IIS is not installed.");
                    iisVersion = (int)iisKey.GetValue("MajorVersion");
                }

                return iisVersion;
            }

        }

        public static IList<IisWebSite> GetIisSites()
        {
            List<IisWebSite> sites = new List<IisWebSite>();

            using (DirectoryEntry iisRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC"))
            {
                iisRoot.RefreshCache();
                sites.AddRange(iisRoot.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Where(w => w.SchemaClassName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == "iiswebserver").Select(w => new IisWebSite(w.Name, w.Properties["ServerComment"].Value.ToString())));
            }

            return sites;
        }

        public static IList<string> GetIisAppPools()
        {
            List<string> pools = new List<string>();
            using (DirectoryEntry poolRoot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/AppPools"))
            {
                poolRoot.RefreshCache(); pools.AddRange(poolRoot.Children.Cast<DirectoryEntry>().Select(p => p.Name));
            }
            return pools;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post, most specifically, the last paragraph. It's very possible that it's a 32bit vs 64bit DLL compilation conflict

> Both the customer and I were creating 32-bit .NET applications, and
>   the COM interface for the FTP runtime state is implemented in a
>   64-bit-only DLL. Once we both changed our projects to compile for
>   64-bit platforms, we were both able to get the code to run.
>   (Coincidentally, all I had was a 32-bit system when I wrote my
>   original blog, so I probably would have run into this sooner if I had
>   owned a 64-bit system way back then. ;-])

http://blogs.iis.net/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/06/29/error-class-not-registered-0x80040154-when-querying-ftp-runtime-state.aspx